# How to export fills on Freestyle SVG export?

Tags: export, edges, freestyle

I have a simple cube object with a blue diffuse color. I enable the freestyle svg plugin and check all the necessary boxes. Freestyle exports the edges to the .SVG but there are no colors present.
Do I have to do something specific to export the materials as fills?

Answer (score 5):

The [SVG exporter](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Freestyle) only supports exporting the freestyle lines at the moment.
If you want to have the fill in your SVG file as well, you can use the [trace bitmap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-xxhphybnE) function in inkscape (or a similar action in other vector graphics programs) on your rendered image.

This is a little bit beyond strict blender topics, but I don't think there's a way to do this without external programs.

http://i.giphy.com/l41lKvw47mA396Ei4.gif

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If what you say is true, what is this "Exporting fills" section in the documentation page? http://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/export_svg.html#exporting-fills

Comment: From a few tests I performed, it does fill the space inside the curves, but in a fairly rudimentary way and with a single color.

Comment: Could you perhaps link the .blend file?

Comment: Here's a simple example with a cylinder: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38340
You can see the difference between the filled SVG and the rendered image here: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/93673

Answer (score 4):

The [Blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/export_svg.html#exporting-fills) seems to suggest you can do this but I've never gotten this to work. I also wrote a different guide on [exporting lines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98524/how-to-render-3d-models-as-svg-vector-graphics-planar-projection/197711#197711), but for your needs there is an [SVG output script](https://github.com/Nutek/blender_export_svg) that does what you need.

Once you have it installed press N to bring up object properties. At the bottom a new panel should be there called Export SVG.

[image]

This script exports based on the current view. There are loads of settings you can try but for basic export choose your export location and then press Export SVG. Now, when you open it in Inkscape you should have an SVG with fills.

[image]

If you want to smooth the vector file you'll have to manually merge the objects (Ctrl + Shift + +).