# A quick way to convert 3D models into 2D

Tags: modeling, modifiers, conversion, svg

I'm trying to convert the **3D model** of a humanoid mesh a **2D flat** model,because I've thought : since I want to do the **projection painting** of an hand drawn image that's 2D,that you can see below :

[image: tamara]

if I want to get the best result I should use a **2D mesh**. I have found this thread :

[Convert a 3d model into a simple 2d model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78884/convert-a-3d-model-into-a-simple-2d-model/78889)

and I have used that tecnique to make the **conversion**. Below you can see what's the result. The **rendered image** is good,but the exported **svg file is not good**. The worst problem of this tecnique is that the mesh is **without textures** ; there are a lot of **doubles** ; the body is not splitted into **single parts**...do you know if there is another tecnique or a combination of modifiers that gives a better result ?

This is the rendered 2D image :

[image: 1]

This is the exported svg file :

[image: 2]

Comment: check the following question [How to export fills on Freestyle SVG export?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39353/how-to-export-fills-on-freestyle-svg-export)