# Is it possible to import a Blender render to Adobe Animate/Illustrator with layers?

Tags: export, import

I am a newbie in Blender and all the terminology is kind of confusing but my main question is if:

- I create a 3D setting/environment in Blender
- Render it as an Image
- Import this image in Adobe Animate/Illustrator (to be used as a background)

Each object to be a separate layer/(2d vectors?) and as such i can animate and draw behind or in front of the objects made in Blender

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [render 3d mesh to 2d svg export](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23661/render-3d-mesh-to-2d-svg-export) or [can blender export 2d curves to SVG](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg)

Comment: read also [how to export fills on freestyle svg export](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39353/how-to-export-fills-on-freestyle-svg-export)

Answer (score 0):

You can import Jpeg in Adobe illustrator. Blender has the ability to export jpegs.

Comment: Jpeg is neither vector based nor conserves layers, as requested by the OP